# char array keeps the last element stored

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have written a code to read strings from a file and store them in a char array. The problem is that when I print the strings previously stored I just get that every element of the array has the same information stored at the end of the while loop.

The problem is with the arrays "ori" and "des". After the while loop I print the information in them but I just get the last item stores repeated again and again.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

FILE *f;

int sale[31];
int llega[31];
char* ori[31];
char* des[31];
int i;
int j;
char string1 [31];
char string2 [31];
char string3 [31];
char string4 [31];

f=fopen("rol.txt","rt");
i = 0;
while((fscanf(f,"%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\n]\n", string1, string2, string3, string4 ))!= EOF){

    printf( "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", string1, string2, string3, string4 );
    sale[i] = strtol(string1, NULL, 10);
    llega[i] = strtol(string4, NULL, 10);   

    ori[i] = string2; //Here is where I think I am storing the value of string2
    des[i] = string3; //Here is where I think I am storing the value of string3     
    i++;            
}

for (j = 0; j < 31; j++ ){      
    printf("%s %s %d\n",ori[j],des[j],j); //Here for every "j" I get the same result    
}   
fclose(f);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ori[i]` is a pointer, not a string.

Comment: Is `ori[i]= &string2[0]` the same as `ori[i] = string2` ?

Comment: Oli, the thing is that if I use an array of chars instead of the pointer "ori" then i cant assign the value of string2 to it. I get this type of error:  error #2168: Operands of '=' have incompatible types 'char' and 'char *'.

Comment: Igor, I tried as you said with exactly the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is an expected behavior as `char* ori[31]` is a array of character pointer. The statement `ori[i] = string2`(`ori[i] = &string2[0]` both are similar thing) assigns the address of `string2`. So all `ori[i]` will contain the content of what `string2` holds now (In this case, it is the last assignment of while loop).

**Using array of strings**

create array of char string:

```
char ori[31][31];
char des[31][31];
```

And assign like

```
strcpy(ori[i], string2);
strcpy(des[i], string3);
```

Or...

**Using `std::string`** ( If you're using C++ )

You can use:

```
string ori[31];
string des[31];
```

and

```
ori[i] = string(string2);
des[i] = string(string3);
```

and print as `printf("%s\t%s\n", ori[j].c_str(), des[j].c_str())`

Also you need to import header `<string>`

Comment: Thanks, but then how can I store the content of `string2` and not the address?

Comment: I am coding in C, I made the changes you suggested but i guess it is for C++. Sorry if I am wrong but I got confused. Anyway i got plenty of errors that that is why I think it might be related to the it

Comment: Check my second edit. You can easily follow the **First way**

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working. Would it be too much to ask if you can shed some light as to why the double [31][31]?

Comment: It is a 2 dimensional array. In this case, it means **array of *array of characters (string)***.